Unable to communicate with odd tentacles after Octopus Server Upgrade
We upgraded the version of our Octopus server to 2024.1.12815 and it worked well for the most part but one or two tentacles are now timing out.
Issues we had to mitigate with the upgrade:

Upgrading the servers to .NET 4.8
Upgrading Calamari
Upgrading the tentacles

However now after all this there are one or two problem tentacles who although showing healthy are displaying "Could not communicate with Tentacle after 301 seconds." when trying to deploy. We have checked the network connectivity between the Octopus Server and the tentacles and visa versa.
Using tentacle version 8.1.558

I'm facing the exact same problem!
Initially, I found some threads on GitHub suggesting it may be a Schannel protocol misalignment - Talks of TLS v1.2 is required for Tentacle versions 3.1 and up.
https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/1902
In my testing I have switched to strictly TLS v1.2 and enabling all previous versions with no change or success. If I come across a fix, I'll post it back here.
UPDATE:
Turns out that the issue we had was because of a corrupt package when downloading from cache. After recreating the package we were able to deploy successfully.
